# Frame.Navigate crashes when passed a Page-derived class from dynamically-loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, frame, winui

The design of my application is such that some assemblies can be dynamically loaded at runtime (unknown at compile time). This is a typical 'plug-in' type architecture where I can discover Page-derived classes in the dynamically loaded assembly via reflection. The design works fine in WPF and WinForms applications where we manage our own windows, frames, and 'navigation'.

With WinUI3, the call to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(...)` throws an exception when I pass as the first parameter the type of the Page-derived class from the dynamically loaded assembly. The same code works fine if I put this Page-derived class into an assembly that is referenced by the main app exe.

The exception is 6-calls deep in Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll in the stack, and is:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')'

Does anyone have any experience with whether this is supposed to work, or if this is a known bug? Or a known (permanent) limitation of the navigate architecture & infrastructure in WinUI3?

Comment: This may seem vague but maybe you can ensure the dynamically loaded assembly is fully loaded before passing it into `Frame.Navigate`. Right now, it seems like it is trying to  instantly the xaml too fast. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160281/17985195) could help you if you convert it into an object before navigating it

Comment: That's a good thought. I have tested calling Activator.CreateInstance() to create an instance of the dynamically loaded type right before calling the navigate. And that CreateInstance succeeds.  So, while a good idea, I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: FWIW, the issue in the link below is almost exactly like this issue, except I am using a Page instead of a UserControl, and I am using Frame.Navigate().  The workarounds in this issue didn't help my situation.
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3888

Comment: I have disabled 'Just My Code' and stepped into the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Conrols.Frame.Navigate implementation as deeply as necessary, and eventually there is a call to global::System.Type.GetType(text) where text is the proper full name/URI of my dynamically loaded Page-derived type. 
That function returns null which is the source of the issue. 
Apparently the type system isn't able to look up this dynamically loaded type.